# Save text from a textField after editing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got 2 textField and when the user types something in, and pushes the return button or back button on my navigation controller, that it saves the textFields. I've already tried this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   NSLog(@"textFieldShouldEndEditing");

   return YES;
}
```

but this doesn't print out anything. The names of my two textFields are self.CellOne.textField and self.CellTwo.textField and I've also added the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` delegate in my class. What I actually want is whenever the foces goes off the textFields, it needs to be saved.

Comment: aren't your textfield delegates called?

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; THIS METHOD IS CALLED

Comment: Check if you not forget to set!
`self.CellOne.textField.delegate = self;` `self.CellTwo.textField.delegate = self;`

Comment: Did you set 'self' or the controller respectively properly as the text field's delegate? You need to do that either programmatically or in IB if you used IB.

Comment: Damn, I had forgotten that, thanks!